# How do I set the default qt to 5.0 or later?

Tags: package-management, python, qt, pyqt, qmake

I installed the latest version of qt in order to install eric6. Another dependency is pyqt.

When I run `python configure.py` I get the following **error**:

```
qmake: could not exec '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake': No such file or directory
Error: PyQt5 requires Qt v5.0 or later. You seem to be using v3. Use the --qmake flag to specify the correct version of qmake.'
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: How exactly did you install Qt? is package `qt5-qmake` installed?

Comment: I  installed Qt via their .run online install script.  I just installed qt5-qmake with apt but 4.7 is still the default.  How do I use the --qmake flag to specify which version is to be used? I can't seem to get the formatting right.

Comment: Based on the [Building and Installing from Source](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/installation.html) it looks like you'd run something like `python configure.py --qmake=/path/to/qt5/bin/qmake`. Or you could try either setting a `QT_SELECT` shell variable; or running the `qtchooser` command if one is installed.